# Params field is empty in $router.push

Tags: vue.js, url-parameters, vue-resource, vue-router

Consider this:

```
this.$root.$router.push({
    path: '/dashboard', 
    params: { errors: 'error' }, 
    query: { test: 'test' }
})
```

I use this in my component to redirect to another URL, and some error has occured. The problem is that when I want to access `params` field in dashboard component, it's empty. The `query` field works well. I'm trying to access it by `this.$route.params.errors`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use `params` only with `named` paths (i think).

Example:

```
//route (in your router file should have "name")
{ path: '/errors', name: 'EXAMPLE', component: ... }

//navigating
this.$router.push({
    name: 'EXAMPLE', 
    params: { errors: '123' }
});
```

Now it will have correct value in `this.$route.params`.

Comment: Do you know what's the reason for this limitation?

Comment: Tragic limitation.

Comment: what a gotchya.... not enough to just push the route path and params in object

Comment: This explanation does not obey the intro in official https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html. I think this is a bug of Vuejs

Comment: how about this.$router.currentRoute.params.id? its only work with buttong with `:to properties only` , with `this.$router.push` doesnt work.

Answer (score 12):

If you *don't* want to use *named routes* you can try this:

**ES6**

```
this.$root.$router.push({
    path: `/dashboard/${error}`, 
    query: { test }
})
```

**ES5**

```
this.$root.$router.push({
    path: '/dashboard/' + error, 
    query: { test: 'test' }
})
```

Comment: Query probably might not handle objects like `props` do (not tested tho)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue where in one of my views (component). I was trying to navigate (programmatically) from `/foo/bar` to `/foo/bar/123`, but the route param was not available later in the component. My relevant navigation code looked like below:

```
methods: {
  save_obj() {
    let vm = this;
    // Make AJAX call to save vm.my_obj, and on success do:
    let v = `${vm.$route.path}/${vm.my_obj.id}`;
    console.log("Loading view at path: "+v);
    vm.$router.push({ path: v });
  },
    ...
}
```

It would print the expected log (e.g., Loading view at path: /foo/bar/112), however, the loading of data in the `created()` hook would not receive the value of route param. My failing `created()` code looked like below:

```
created: function() {
      console.log("Loading object details.");
      let vm = this;
      let cid = vm.$route.params.id; // <---- This was the problem
      vm.$http.get('api/'+cid)
      .then(function (res) {
        if (res.data.status == "OK") {
          vm.my_obj = res.data.body;
        } else {
          vm.setStatusMessage(res.data.body);
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        vm.setStatusMessage("Error: "+error);
      });
}
```

The solution was indicated in [the **third note** here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) quoted below :

> Note: If the destination is the same as the current route and only
> params are changing (e.g. going from one profile to another /users/1
> -> /users/2), you will have to use beforeRouteUpdate to react to changes (e.g. fetching the user information).

I had to do the following in my component:

Change the line `let cid = vm.$route.params.id;` in `created()` to `let cid = vm.course.id`

and, add the following to the component:

```
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    if (to.params.id) {
      this.my_obj.id = to.params.id;
    }
    // Some other code specific to my app
    next();
  }
```

I hope this helps someone stuck with the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a parameter with a query parameter you can use that syntax like that

```
this.$router.push({
    path: this.localePath(`/bookings/${requestReservation?.attributes?.booking_id}`),
    query: { requestReservation: requestReservation }
})
```

You can access it on the next page like that

```
this.$route.query.requestReservation
```

If you want send it fro nuxt-link than its syntax like that

```
<nuxt-link 
 :to="{ path: '/bookings/'+ requestReservation.attributes.booking_id, 
 query: { requestReservation } }">
 Booking
</nuxt-link>
```

You can access it on the next page same like previous

```
this.$route.query.requestReservation
```